# Сonditional color formatting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, styling

Task in Conditional Formatting (Using styling i guess)
Python,Pandas

There is a plate with two columns

the second table should be highlighted
conditions:

1. in green if the 1st columns number exceeds the second one;
2. yellow if the 1st columns number is equal to the second one;
3. in red if the 1st columns number is less than second one.[[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @jezrael your link talks about images of code. Why not images of small snippets of data?

Comment: @SachinPrabhu - because same problem - cannot copy data

Comment: @jezrael Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create new DataFrame filled by styles by condition with [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html), for set rows by conditions is used [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: green'
    c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c3 = 'background-color: red'

    m1 = x.iloc[:, 0] > x.iloc[:, 1]
    m2 = x.iloc[:, 0] == x.iloc[:, 1]

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c3, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    return df1.mask(m1, c1).mask(m2, c2)

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

EDIT:

If need set only one column use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: green'
    c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c3 = 'background-color: red'
    c = ''

    m1 = x.iloc[:, 0] > x.iloc[:, 1]
    m2 = x.iloc[:, 0] == x.iloc[:, 1]

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.iloc[:, 1] = np.select([m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3)
    return df1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply column formatting using `pandas.DataFrame.style.apply` and some formatting functions: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: Please add some of the formatting functions here in case the link breaks at some point in the future.